# Copy the xml nodes to one location to another location with the help of xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform the following xml.

## This is my source xml:

```
<DST>
  <DST>
    <PQAWD>
      <username>#username#</username>
      <password>#password#</password>
      <newPassword/>
    </PQAWD>
  </DST>
  <CacheRequest>
    <getCache AWDConfig="Y">
      <useClientName>N</useClientName>
      <useGlobalCache>Y</useGlobalCache>
      <keyName>AWDConfig</keyName>
      <targetNode>.</targetNode>
    </getCache>
  </CacheRequest>
  <AWDConfig>
    <IPAddress>$host-address$</IPAddress>
    <XMLPort>$host-port$</XMLPort>
    <scriptHostName>######</scriptHostName>
  </AWDConfig>
</DST>
```

## Explanation:

The above XML has to be converted into the desired output as shown below.
These are the nodes I have to transform:

- `//AWDConfig/IPAddress` should be moved under `//DST/PQAWD` and renamed to `hostAddress`
- `//AWDconfig/XMLPort` should be moved under `//DST/PQAWD` and renamed to `hostPort`

## Desired output:

```
<DST>
  <DST>
    <PQAWD>
      <username>#username#</username>
      <password>#password#</password>
      <newPassword/>                
     <hostAddress>$host-address$</hostAddress>     
     <hostPort>$host-port$</hostPort>
    </PQAWD>
  </DST>
  <CacheRequest>
    <getCache AWDConfig="Y">
      <useClientName>N</useClientName>
      <useGlobalCache>Y</useGlobalCache>
      <keyName>AWDConfig</keyName>
      <targetNode>.</targetNode>
    </getCache>
  </CacheRequest>
  <AWDConfig>
    <IPAddress>$host-address$</IPAddress>
    <XMLPort>$host-port$</XMLPort>
  </AWDConfig>
</DST>
```

Comment: thanks don for formatted correctly...

Comment: Please include your XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: 1) You say you want the `IPAddress` and `XMLPort` *moved*, but they are still in the result document (do you actually want them *copied*? instead of *moved*?). 2) Try dedicating an hour to study a bit of XSLT and try to transform your document with a simple stylesheet. If you don't find the answer, post the stylesheet here (But you might even find the answer yourself. If that happens, then you can post it as an answer here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="newPassword">
<xsl:value-of select="parent::DST/AWDConfig/IPAddres"/>
<xsl:copy/>
<hostAddress><xsl:value-of select="../../../AWDConfig/IPAddress"/></hostAddress>     
<hostPort><xsl:value-of select="../../../AWDConfig/XMLPort"/></hostPort>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="//DST/PQAWD">
      <PQAWD>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
         <hostAddress>
            <xsl:value-of select="//AWDConfig/IPAddress" />
         </hostAddress>
         <hostPort>
            <xsl:value-of select="//AWDConfig/XMLPort" />
         </hostPort>
      </PQAWD>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DST>
   <DST>
      <PQAWD>
         <username>#username#</username>
         <password>#password#</password>
         <newPassword />
         <hostAddress>$host-address$</hostAddress>
         <hostPort>$host-port$</hostPort>
      </PQAWD>
   </DST>
   <CacheRequest>
      <getCache AWDConfig="Y">
         <useClientName>N</useClientName>
         <useGlobalCache>Y</useGlobalCache>
         <keyName>AWDConfig</keyName>
         <targetNode>.</targetNode>
      </getCache>
   </CacheRequest>
   <AWDConfig>
      <IPAddress>$host-address$</IPAddress>
      <XMLPort>$host-port$</XMLPort>
      <scriptHostName>######</scriptHostName>
   </AWDConfig>
</DST>
```